# Any way to use academicons with pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, academicons

From what I gather [here](https://github.com/diogo-fernan/academicons), the author mentions:

> *The academicons package provides access in **(La)TeX** to 76 high quality icons of online academic profiles included in the **free Academicons font**. This package requires either the **Xe(La)TeX** or **Lua(La)TeX** engine to load the Academicons font from the system, which requires installing the bundled `academicons.ttf` font file. As new releases come out, it is recommended to install the bundled font version as there may be differences between the package and previous font versions or newest font versions not yet contemplated in the package.*

I suppose this means there is no way to use this package with `pdfLaTeX`. If so, is there any other way to use in pdfLaTeX a **specific symbol** from the actual underlying [Academicons **font**](https://jpswalsh.github.io/academicons/)? 
E.g. google-scholar's icon: [image]

Comment: I know there are ways to load glyphs from a TTF, but one very general approach is to compile something into a standalone PDF with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and include it in PDFLaTeX as if it were a figure.

Comment: If you only want to use a single symbol from a font, you can change that symbol into a graphic and then include the graphic instead via `\includegraphics`. For example, `\newcommand{\googlescholar}{\includegraphics[width=1ex]{google_scholar}}` where `google_scholar.pdf` is a cropped version of the symbol.

Comment: You need a tfm for pdflatex and perhaps an enc file. It is not difficult to create this, but for one or two icons using an image as suggested by Werner is quite sensible.